# Problems with preparedStatement in an insert query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I have a table in a MySQL database which is 13 columns, the first one is auto-increment and the rest are normal, I have this:

```
    SQL="INSERT INTO cuentas (id_proveedor_cloud,id_esquema_asociado,id_tipo_cuenta,n_cuenta,nombre_cuenta,cod_cliente"+ 
            "descuento,f_creacion,borrado,f_borrado,id_cuenta_ccis,logo)"+
            " VALUES("+             
            "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

            this.pstm = this.conexion.prepareStatement(SQL);
            this.pstm.setInt(1, proveedor);
            this.pstm.setInt(2, esquema);
            this.pstm.setInt(3, cuenta.getNivel());
            this.pstm.setString(4,num_c);
            this.pstm.setString(5, cuenta.getNombre_cuenta());
            this.pstm.setString(6, "");
            this.pstm.setDouble(7, cuenta.getDescuento());
            this.pstm.setString(8,dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).toString());
            this.pstm.setBoolean(9, cuenta.isBorrado());
            if(cuenta.isBorrado()==false){
               this.pstm.setString(10,null);
            }else{
                this.pstm.setString(10, dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).toString());
            }
            this.pstm.setInt(11, cuenta.getId_cuenta_padre());
           this.pstm.setBytes(12, cuenta.getLogo());
int ejecutado =  this.pstm.executeUpdate();
```

I have the next mistake: `java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`, why?

The column which is auto-increment it's not here obviously, so without it, they are 12 columns.

Comment: Are `cod_cliente` and `descuento` two separate columns, or one column? In your string, they **seem** to be one column (no comma), but that means you only have 11 rather than 12.

Comment: Thanks, it was because of that.

Answer (score 3):

The error you posted is very clear, the column names that you listed doesn't match the values listed in the `VALUES` clause, thats probably because you missed out the `,` in the end of the first line, try this instead:

```
                                           You missed this , here------
                                                                      |
INSERT INTO cuentas (id_proveedor_cloud,id_esquema_asociado,         \|/
                     id_tipo_cuenta,n_cuenta,nombre_cuenta,cod_cliente, 
            descuento,f_creacion,borrado,f_borrado,id_cuenta_ccis,logo
VALUES("+             
            "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 11 fields in your names, but 12 question marks.

You're probably missing a `,` at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You have only 11 fields

```
cuentas (id_proveedor_cloud,
id_esquema_asociado,
id_tipo_cuenta,
n_cuenta,
nombre_cuenta,
cod_clientedescuento,
f_creacion,
borrado,
f_borrado,
id_cuenta_
ccis,logo)
```